# DateTime.AddDays in a While loop. What am I missing?

Tags: c#

I have a datetime object, `dt`,  that holds today's date.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
DateTime idt = new DateTime();
```

I need to print the date when the loop reaches last day of the current year, like this:
 `345 more days to 12/31/2012`

If I do it this way

```
while (dt.AddDays(i).Year == dt.Year) 
{
    idt = dt.AddDays(i);
    i++;
}
Console.WriteLine("{0} more days to {1}", i, idt.ToString("d"));
```

I am able to get it to print like I want:  `345 more days to 1/1/2012`

I want to avoid the repetition of `dt.AddDays(i)` in the above part. If I do it either this way:

```
while (idt.Year != dt.Year + 1)
{
    idt = dt.AddDays(i);
    i++;
}
Console.WriteLine("{0} more days to {1}", i, idt.ToString("d"));
```

or this way:

```
while (idt.Year < 2013)
{
    idt = dt.AddDays(i);
    i++;
} 
Console.WriteLine("{0} more days to {1}", i, idt.ToString("d"));
```

I get the output as `346 more days to 1/1/2013`.

I am definitely missing something painfully obvious, but I am unable to figure out. What would it be?

Comment: Why aren't you using `TimeSpan` to calculate the days?

Comment: I am not aware of it until now. Will look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just

```
int days = new DateTime(dt.Year, 12, 31).Subtract(dt).Days;
```

?

Answer (score 6):

You can calculate the difference using `TimeSpan` instead:

```
var nextYear = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, 31, 12);
var timeToNextYear = nextYear - DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
var daysToNextYear = timeToNextYear.TotalDays;
```

Comment: Your counting the days until the end of *next* year, which happns tto be negative, too.

Comment: You're still counting the days until the end of next year, don't add one to DateTime.UtcNow.Year.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases the condition in the while loop evaluates to true on December 31st 2012, then inside the loop one more day is added, setting idt to 1/1/2013.

You can simply get the number of remaining days of the year like this:

```
int days = (new DateTime(dt.Year, 12, 31) - dt).TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in this code

```
while (idt.Year < 2013)
{
    idt = dt.AddDays(i);
    i++;
}
```

idt.year has the same value for the first two iterations of the loop, because you are incrementing by 0.

Change it to this:

```
while (idt.Year < 2013)
{
    i++;
    idt = dt.AddDays(i);
}
```

and you'll get the right result.

By the way you can do this as a one-liner:

```
int days = (DateTime.Parse("1/1/" + ((DateTime.Now.Year) + 1).ToString()) - DateTime.Now).Days;
```

If your code will needs to work in various locales then you'd need to use an overload of DateTime.Parse that provides an IFormatProvider so that 1/1/yyyy will always parse.